# Center div and position element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate something like [this](http://mrcthms.com/?ref=hackernoon.com) but now I'm having a few issues. The first issue I have is to center my 'main' div I went and did it like this:

```
body{
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, #fdcd3b 60%, #ffed4b 60%);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

But because of the 'position: fixed' my background is not shown anymore which I added in the body.

An other issue I have is on the site I want to recreate there are 2 p elements next to each other [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjQTU.png) but I can't manage to get my 2 p elements next to each other with this code:

```
p{
  margin: 0;
  display:inline;
  float:left;
}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5VW4.png) is how my p element looks like and also my whole html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Practice site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c934cb6477.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
    <body>

      <main class="container">

        <!-- <header>
          <div class="header">
          </div>
        </header> -->

        <div class="main">
          <h1>Hey, I'm test</h1>
          <h2>Student software developer.</h2>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquam arcu et urna placerat dignissim. Nulla nec sollicitudin lorem, at maximus lorem. Cras porta quis sapien ut ornare. Nullam nec sem molestie, scelerisque sapien sit amet, dignissim ex. Sed eget felis gravida, maximus risus a, sodales libero. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquam arcu et urna placerat dignissim. Nulla nec sollicitudin lorem, at maximus lorem. Cras porta quis sapien ut ornare. Nullam nec sem molestie, scelerisque sapien sit amet, dignissim ex. Sed eget felis gravida, maximus risus a, sodales libero. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
        </div>


        <footer class="bg-dark text-center text-white footer fixed-bottom">
          <div class="container p-4 pb-0">
            <section class="mb-4">
              <!-- Linkedin -->
              <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#" target="_blank" role="button"
                ><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i
              ></a>
        
              <!-- Github -->
              <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#" target="_blank" role="button"
                ><i class="fab fa-github"></i
              ></a>

             <!-- CV -->
             <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#" target="_blank" role="button"
             ><i class="fa-regular fa-address-card"></i
           ></a>
         </section>
          </div>
        
          <!-- Copyright -->
          <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
            © 
            <span id="current-year"></span>
            Copyright:
            <a class="text-white">test</a>
          </div>
        </footer>

      </main>

      <script src="/Files/Js/function.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have found a question that has answers that would be solutions to this one, please vote to close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your thought proccess, but unfortunately, it's not quite right. You see, the initial page was done entirely differently from the start:

Instead of centering the main div, the creator of the page gave the body a padding of `64px`, and then made the wrapper div sized at `100%` width and `100% - 64px * 2` height. So, to do that:

```css
body{
  padding:64px;
}
.wrapper{
  height:calc(100vh - 64px * 2);
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

You can see I added a border as well so that you can see where the wrapper is located. Why did I not simply just set `height:100%` and instead did that confusing math thing with different units? Well, setting a percentage height would return `0`, so I had to take the height of the entire page, then subtract the padding of the body multiplied by 2 to actually achieve that.

What he did next (I'll assume it's a "he", no offense here) was to make the wrapper a flexbox with it's direction being along the column, and justify it's contents in `space-between`, meaning that the content will be put in the center of te space between the others. While having a header and a footer displayed on the top and bottom of the wrapper accordingly, we put a content div, with it's contents horizontally aligned to the center. You can see that it's justified along the center of the space between the header and the footer, achieving what we asked for. Working snippet:

```css
body{
  padding:64px;
}
.wrapper{
  height:calc(100vh - 64px * 2);
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.content{
  align-self:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="content">
    Blah blah
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Let's continue separately from the original from now on, as the way it was made makes it too hard to understand.

We will make a div that will act as a grid, then put 2 separate rows into it. Each row will space its contents differently.

```css
body{
  padding:64px;
}
.wrapper{
  height:calc(100vh - 64px * 2);
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.content{
  align-self:center;
}
.grid{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="row1">Row 1 (Title and Email button)</div>
      <div class="row2">Row 2 (The 2 paragraphs)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

The way the `.grid` div works is by making it a flexbox once again, and aligning its contents along the vertical axis (column), putting the one under the other.

What we will do next is split each row into 2 separate cells, by making each one a flexbox again (I love flexbox) and using `justify-content:space-between`, to put the contents on both ends.

```css
body{
  padding:64px;
}
.wrapper{
  height:calc(100vh - 64px * 2);
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:space-between;
  padding:10px;
}
.content{
  align-self:center;
}
.grid{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.row1, .row2{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.intro{
  padding-right:15px;
}
.bigbutton{
  padding:15px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>(Not making any buttons, using the name "Marc" just to position the elements at first)</header>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="row1">
        <div class="intro">
          <h1>Hey, I'm Marc</h1>
          <h2>Digital designer &amp; front-end developer.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="email">
          <button class="bigbutton">Get in touch</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row2">
        <div class="p1">
        <p>Currently a design systems engineer helping people design better at InVision.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p2">Previously worked with Wonderbly, Vanity Fair, Great Little Place, Glamour, and Discovery Network.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

The above snippet might not look 100% like the initial page (position-wise at least), since it's displayed in such a small space. You can see that we are getting somewhere here. In fact, I think we're done!
To help you further, I will just put some styling here to make it closer to the original.

```css
body{
  padding:64px;
}
.wrapper{
  height:calc(100vh - 64px * 2);
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:space-between;
  padding:10px;
}
.content{
  align-self:center;
}
.grid{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.row1, .row2{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.intro{
  padding-right:15px;
}
.bigbutton{
  padding:15px;
  border:1px solid;
  background-image:linear-gradient(135deg, #e2718d 0%, #E9B626 50%, #e2718d 100%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(8px 0%, calc(100% - 8px) 0%, 100% 8px, 100% calc(100% - 8px), calc(100% - 8px) 100%, 8px 100%, 0% calc(100% - 8px), 0% 8px);
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition:0.3s;
}
.bigbutton:hover{
  background-position:70% 0%;
}

:root{
  font-family:monospace;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>(Not making any buttons, using the name "Marc" just to position the elements at first)</header>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="row1">
        <div class="intro">
          <h1>Hey, I'm Marc</h1>
          <h2>Digital designer &amp; front-end developer.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="email">
          <a href="mailto:your@email.com" class="bigbutton">Get in touch</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row2">
        <div class="p1">
        <p>Currently a design systems engineer helping people design better at InVision.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p2">Previously worked with Wonderbly, Vanity Fair, Great Little Place, Glamour, and Discovery Network.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

I'll leave the rest on you. Hope I didn't get you too tired or confused. Good luck with it!

(EDIT: Damn, the snippets start to look terrible after around the 3rd step. Dont' worry tho, they will be fine in a big enough screen)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this in depth explanation! I never did anything with the grid before so this is a good exercise for me to practice with.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than positioning your main absolutely you can apply display: flex to the body element and set it to 100vh so it covers the viewport. The background will reppear then.

For your p elements, again, wrap them up in a div with display: flex and you and position them side by side like the example below

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, #fdcd3b 60%, #ffed4b 60%);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  /*display flex allows you the center the main element in the middle of your page */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main {
  /* not needed */
}

.inline-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.inline {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c934cb6477.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<main class="container">

  <!-- <header>
          <div class="header">
          </div>
        </header> -->

  <div class="main">
    <h1>Hey, I'm test</h1>
    <h2>Student software developer.</h2>
    <div class="inline-container">
      <p class="inline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquam arcu et urna placerat dignissim. Nulla nec sollicitudin lorem, at maximus lorem. Cras porta quis sapien ut ornare. Nullam nec sem molestie, scelerisque sapien sit amet, dignissim
        ex. Sed eget felis gravida, maximus risus a, sodales libero. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
      <p class="inline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquam arcu et urna placerat dignissim. Nulla nec sollicitudin lorem, at maximus lorem. Cras porta quis sapien ut ornare. Nullam nec sem molestie, scelerisque sapien sit amet, dignissim
        ex. Sed eget felis gravida, maximus risus a, sodales libero. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <footer class="bg-dark text-center text-white footer fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container p-4 pb-0">
      <section class="mb-4">
        <!-- Linkedin -->
        <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#" target="_blank" role="button"><i
              class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>

        <!-- Github -->
        <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#" target="_blank" role="button"><i
              class="fab fa-github"></i></a>

        <!-- CV -->
        <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="#" target="_blank" role="button"><i
              class="fa-regular fa-address-card"></i></a>
      </section>
    </div>

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
      ©
      <span id="current-year"></span> Copyright:
      <a class="text-white">test</a>
    </div>
  </footer>

</main>

<script src="/Files/Js/function.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```